# What languages use $_variable notation and how they use it differently? beside PERL

Tags: php, perl, variables

I know PERL uses $_variable, but what other langages use the $_variable notation and how is it different than PERL?

Comment: You should probably rephrase that question.

Comment: Does this question ask for ① languages with default variables (the Perl `$_` translates to English `it` or `this`; Perl6 introduces lots of new awesomness), or ② for languages with Sigils (`$%@&*` in Perl), which are a kind of Hungarian Notation, or ③ specifically for the `$` character in programming languages?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby for example uses this notation as in `$global_variables`